# How do I set up VirtualBox 'multi-site' test lab?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox installed on a machine at home. What I would like to accomplish is to set up two (or maybe more) different subnets within the Internal network (completely isolated from my home LAN).

What I'm aiming to achieve: I would like to set up a test an Active Directory 'multi-site' environment, where site-to-site replication can be configured and tinkered with between the two or more internal networks.

I have read somewhere about PfSense, which acts as a router, but I'm unsure of how to set up communication between the two subnets/VLANS once PfSense is installed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample network diagram:

[image: Network Diagram]

In this setup you have 3 separate internal networks.  The "public" network represents the Internet or WAN, the "lan1" and "lan2" networks represent your site networks.  To set this up you would need at least 4 VMs:  2 pfSense routers and 2 AD boxes.   You could then connect as many workstation or server machines to each network as you'd like for your testing.